# Fatal error: Class 'Hash' not found, CakePhp-2

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to run a CakePhp-2 project but it shows the error:
Fatal error: Class 'Hash' not found in G:\xampp\htdocs\leaping\project\erg_payroll\lib\Cake\Core\Configure.php on line 165

Comment: Check if this file exists Cake/Utility/Hash.php.

Comment: It was missing and I put it from another CakePhp-2 project but error still showing

Comment: Hash class is there from cakephp 2.5 . If you are using any lesser version you will get this error. Either you upgrade the version or put a include this file in your index.php

Comment: Oh! There was missing the 'Utility' folder in 'lib/Cake/'  directory and I have put the directory and solved. Thanks.

Comment: Please appreciate my effort and upvote the comment.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have the folder seeing and the lib folder with the items you really need